# Compare magnitude of integers with limited computation

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics

I have a polynomial $f:\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}$ and very large integers $n, x$ such that $f(n)\approx x$ (specifically, I can say that $f(n)$ is within some relatively small value $\epsilon$ of $x$). However, since $n$ is large, finding $f(n)$ is slow. To check if $f(n)=x$, I can choose $p_1,p_2,...,p_m$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^m p_i>\epsilon$ and see if $f(n)\equiv x\mod p_i$ for $i=1,...,m$. However, this doesn't let me determine if $f(n)>x$ or $f(n)<x$. I think you can solve the Chinese Remainder Theorem and indirectly use the result, but as this is quadratic with respect to the digits of $\epsilon$ (the digits of $\epsilon$ is linear relative to the digits of $n$), this isn't significantly faster if at all compared to direct multiplication with Toom-3 or Schönhage–Strassen. Is there a better approach to using limited information from $f(n)$ to compare it to $x$?

Comment: What is the larger context of this? Is this part of some sort of closest-point / closest-vector search in a lattice? If so, is LLL reduction applicable? What is a typical value of $m$, and how many integers $n$ are there typically per polynomial function $f$? I am asking because in the evaluation of polynomials one can trade-off multiplications with additions at the cost of some pre-computation.

Comment: @njuffa It's not a lattice problem, but preprocessing might be helpful. For a bit more context, there's several million values of n for a degree 4 polynomial f. Those values of n generally have hundreds of thousands of digits. There's not a lot more context as it's primarily recreational.

Comment: Knuth, TAOCP, vol. 2, 3rd ed., section 4.6.4, shows how to evaluate a general fourth degree polynomial with three multiplications and five additions. The pre-computation required is to compute the adapted coefficients for this alternative form. This *may* be applicable to your use case depending on the restrictions (if any) placed on the coefficients.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for the recommendation! I've looked at it before (it's equivalent to the preprocessing example on the Wikipedia page "Polynomial evaluation") and thought it didn't work but some careful reformulation allows it to work with only integers and a few added bit-shifts!

Answer (score 1):

No.  I doubt there is any good method to perform such a comparison.

I'm not aware of any method for that.

Moreover, if there was such a comparison method, then it could be used to compute $f(n)$.  In particular, you could use binary search together with the hypothetical comparison method to compute the value of $f(n)$.  If the hypothetical comparison method is very fast, that provides a fairly fast way to compute $f(n)$.  It seems implausible that there is a faster way to compute $f(n)$ than the existing known methods.  If you believe that, then it places some limits on how fast you could perform such a comparison.  This is not a rigorous proof of impossibility, but hopefully it lends some evidence that it is implausible such a method exists.

An alternative approach: What you could do is compute $f(n) \bmod m$, for some modulus $m=\epsilon$ (or $m=2\epsilon$), then use that value together with $x$ to infer $f(n)$.  (The exact value of $m$ will depend on what exactly you mean by saying $f(n)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $x$.)  You can compute $f(n) \bmod m$ in time linear in $\deg f$ and quadratic in $\log m$.  This is better than computing $f(n)$ from scratch.

Comment: That all makes sense, thanks! f(n) mod m seems like a pretty obvious technique in retrospect which should be a modest improvement over calculating f(n) directly.